# I can't fetch data from this website with Flutter. I've tried everything

Tags: android, flutter, web-scraping

The URL I'm using is: https://www.tefas.gov.tr/TarihselVeriler.aspx

I will fetch the data approximately 5 seconds after the site is loaded; the table is being loaded.

And my codes are as follows:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;

class TumKayitlarSayfasi extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TumKayitlarSayfasiState createState() => _TumKayitlarSayfasiState();
}

class _TumKayitlarSayfasiState extends State<TumKayitlarSayfasi> {
  List<Map<String, String>> extractedData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.tefas.gov.tr/TarihselVeriler.aspx'));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final document = parser.parse(response.body);
        final rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr.odd');

        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10)); // 10 saniye bekleme

        for (final row in rows) {
          final columns = row.children;
          final tarih = columns[0].text.trim();
          final fonKodu = columns[1].text.trim();
          final fonAdi = columns[2].text.trim();
          final fiyat = columns[3].text.trim();

          extractedData.add({
            'tarih': tarih,
            'fonKodu': fonKodu,
            'fonAdi': fonAdi,
            'fiyat': fiyat,
          });
          print(extractedData);
        }

        setState(() {});
      } else {
        print('HTTP Request Error: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error Fetching Data: $e');
    }
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Web Scraping Example'),
      ),
      body: extractedData.isEmpty
          ? Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      )
          : ListView.builder(
        itemCount: extractedData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final data = extractedData[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(data['tarih']!),
            subtitle: Text('${data['fonKodu']} - ${data['fonAdi']}'),
            trailing: Text(data['fiyat']!),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

"I can't retrieve the data that should be fetched with the code you see here. As an example, I'm showing a snippet from the HTML code structure of the website."

```
<tr class="odd"><td class="dt-center sorting_1">18.08.2023</td><td class=" dt-body-center">AAK</td><td class=" dt-body-left">ATA PORTFÖY ÇOKLU VARLIK DEĞİŞKEN FON</td><td class=" dt-body-right">14,902075</td><td class=" dt-body-right">6.703.399,00</td><td class=" dt-body-right">656</td><td class=" dt-body-right">99.894.555,40</td></tr>
```

"I am using my own phone as an emulator. And finally, this website does not publish data on weekends.Thank you in advance for your assistance."

Comment: Which data you need to gather from that site? Only table data?

Comment: yes ,only table data

Comment: https://www.tefas.gov.tr/api/DB/BindHistoryAllocation use this url with `http.post` and parse as json

Comment: "I didn't fully understand what you mean. Could you provide an example? Do we need to enter API credentials?"